# If the multiplication of two operators is hermitian, then will they commute?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

It is proven that if two operators $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{Y}$ commute, then the multiplication of them will be hermitian, i.e. if $\hat{X}\hat{Y}=\hat{Y}\hat{X}$, then $\left(\hat{X}\hat{Y}\right)^\dagger=\hat{X}\hat{Y}$.

My question is that is the opposite true as well? In other words, **if the multiplication of two operators is hermitian, then will they commute**? If yes, I need a proof.

Comment: The identity operator commutes with every other operator, including non-Hermitian ones.  Therefore, the first statement is false.  I suspect the second is false as well. Perhaps you meant to say that if two *Hermitian* operators commute, then their product is Hermitian?

Comment: In fact I saw the relationship in a book. I wanted to know if the opposite is true as well.

Comment: This question is about math, not physics. The answer does not depend on any theory of physics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement of your assertion is a little off, but essentially yes. The correct statement is that two **Hermitian** operators must commute if their product is also Hermitian. The proof is entirely straightforward as a Hermitian product implies $XY=(XY)^\dagger$ but
$$
(XY)^\dagger=Y^\dagger X^\dagger=YX
$$
using that $X$ and $Y$ are both Hermitian themselves. Hence, $XY=YX$.

So, in fact the full statement of the theorem would be **given** two Hermitian operators $X$ and $Y$, the operators commute if and only if their product is also Hermitian.